# Unexplained numpy shape change while looping over image pixels

Tags: python, numpy, edge-detection

I’m attempting to modify code I found at https://towardsdatascience.com/edge-detection-in-python-a3c263a13e03 so I can apply a custom kernel for edge detection of an aerial photo. The test photo I'm using is located here [test1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnJMy.jpg) Its shape is (876, 921, 3).

I’ve rephrased my initial question for clarity –

When I modify the rows in this line

```
horizontal_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+6, col-1:col+4, -1]
```

of my code I get an unexpected shape

```
horizontal_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+5, col-1:col+4, -1] 
#shape =(5,6)
horizontal_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+6, col-1:col+4, -1] 
#shape = (5,6)
horizontal_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+7, col-1:col+4, -1] 
#shape = (5,8)
```

It’s the second line of the above code that throws me.  When I reduce or increase the right exclusive index the shape of my bounding box increases or shrinks in a predictable way with the one exception of row-1:row+6 which I expect to be (5,7) but instead gives me the same shape as row-1:row+5, (5.6).  Why is this happening?

print(img.shape) = (611, 1400, 3)

I'm still something of a python novice and would appreciate any insight into what's going wrong.  Thank you.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#define the vertical filter
vertical_filter = np.array([[-4, -3, -2, 0, 2, 3, 4],
                   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                   [-2, -1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2],
                   [-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3],
                   [-4, -3, -2, 0, 2, 3, 4]])

#define the horizontal filter
horizontal_filter = np.array([[-4, -3, -2, -3, -4],
                     [-3, -2, -1, -2, -3],
                     [-1, -0.5, -0.25, -0.5, -1],
                     [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
                     [1, 0.5, 0.25, 0.5, 1],
                     [3, 2, 1, 2, 3],
                     [4, 3, 2, 3, 4]])

#read in the test image
img = plt.imread('test.png')


#get the dimensions of the image
n,m,d = img.shape

#initialize the edges image
edges_img = img.copy()

#loop over all pixels in the image
for row in range(3, n-2):
    for col in range(3, m-2):
        
        #create little local 7x5 box
        horizontal_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+6, col-1:col+4, 0]
        
        #create little local 5x7 box
        vertical_local_pixels = img[row-1:row+4, col-1:col+6, 0]
         
        #apply the vertical filter
        vertical_transformed_pixels = vertical_local_pixels.transpose().dot(vertical_filter)
        #remap the vertical score
        vertical_score = vertical_transformed_pixels.sum()/4
            
        #apply the horizontal filter
        horizontal_transformed_pixels = horizontal_local_pixels.transpose().dot(horizontal_filter)
        #remap the horizontal score
        horizontal_score = horizontal_transformed_pixels.sum()/4
        
        #combine the horizontal and vertical scores into a total edge score
        edge_score = (vertical_score**2 + horizontal_score**2)**.5
        
        #insert this edge score into the edges image
        edges_img[row, col] = [edge_score]*3
        
#remap the values in the 0-1 range in case they went out of bounds
edges_img = edges_img/edges_img.max()
```

Comment: Why do you think `img[row-1:row+6, col-1:col+4, 0]` is 7x5?

Comment: The code's too complex to read quickly, but I suspect your slicing might be 'running-off-the-edge'.  With both lists and arrays you can slice out of bounds.  `arange(5)[3:np.7]` returns a (2,) result, not (4,).

Comment: Running off the edge makes sense.  Thank you.  I'll take a look at the code with that in mind.

Comment: @Mad Physicist when I initially checked the shape it gave me (7,5).  After your question I went back and checked and it's giving me (6,5) which would be the source of the problem.   I don't understand how to define the bounding box of my filter.

Comment: The right index is exclusive

Comment: Could you double-check whether there's a typo on the `img = plt.imread()` line?

Comment: What's confusing me is that when I modify img[row-1:row+6, col-1:col+4, 0] and change it to img[row-1:row+7, col-1:col+4, 0] it changes the shape to (8,5) instead of (7,5).  I don't understand why that's happening.  ValueError: shapes (5,8) and (7,5) not aligned: 8 (dim 1) != 7 (dim 0)

Comment: I've modified my original question for clarity.  Thank you.

Comment: Consider 1) sharing your input and expected output images, 2) outputting the shape of your image after loading it `print(img.shape)`

Comment: Thank you Mark.  I've shared my input image and it's shape.  I don't have an expected output image to share at this time.

Comment: Presumably you start and end your loops 3 short of the image sides so that you don't index beyond the edge with your 7 px wide/high filter. If so, you should make your little local box not go from `row-1` but from `row-3`. Do you see? Otherwise when you get to 3 rows from the bottom of the image your little box is going to start 4 rows from the bottom but end 2 rows *after* the bottom.

Comment: Also, you should think more clearly about your output image. If you want it in range 0..1, you should make it `float` when you create it and also you should make it a single channel, greyscale image so you don't need to repeat the calculated value in all 3 channels.

Comment: Also, all image processing libraries provide ready-made, error-free, high performance convolution routines so you would do miles better using them - though I do appreciate you may be trying to learn as a purpose.

Comment: Thank you Mark.  I greatly appreciate your feedback and will revisit the code with your suggestions in mind.